Every tight $\tau$-additive finite measure is Radon
According to the 7.2.2 Theorem of the book "Measure Theory" written by V.I. Bogachev, every tight $\tau$-additive finite measure is Radon. The proof says: "The restrictions of a $\tau$-additive measure to all compact subspaces are Radon". That theorem also says that a $\tau$-additive finite measure on a compact Hausdorff space is Radon, so I tried to use this fact. However, I couldn't prove that the restriction of a $\tau$-additive measure to a compact subspaces is also $\tau$-additive.
Below I'll recall some definitions:

A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called Radon if for all $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ and $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a compact set $K\subseteq B$ such that $\mu (B\setminus K)<\varepsilon$.
A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called tight if for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a compact $K\subseteq X$ such that $\mu (X\setminus K)<\varepsilon $.
A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called $\tau$-additive if for every increasing net of open sets $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ in $X$, one has the equality $\mu (\cup _{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda )=\lim_{\lambda}\mu (U_\lambda)$.


My question is: how can I prove that every tight $\tau$-additive measure on a Hausdorff space is also Radon?

Is the underlying space assumed to be Hausdorff? I don’t know how to prove the Hausdorff case, but without the Hausdorff assumption the result is definitely false.

Yes, the underlying space is assume to be Hausdorff. I'll emphasize that.
